# Python subprocess update child-process

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, child-process

Is it possible to update portions of a subprocess spawned via `Popen([cmd], stdin=PIPE)`?

I've been trying to build a script that interacts with a GUI for updating files.
Here is what I've been toying with:

```
def __init__(self):
    #... <SNIPPED>
    process = self.outer._display(self.custom['dialog_name'], _passed, return_process=True)
    # Returns executed list, example -> ['/bin/foo', '--bar', '0', '--lyn', 'twenty']
    self.pipe = subprocess.Popen(process, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The pipe is built in the `__init__` of my class. I want to be able to run the following function to update the process.

```
def update(self, bar, lyn):
    self.pipe.communicate('--bar {} --lyn {}\n'.format(bin, lyn))
```

After running the update function after initializing the class containing the *pipe*, the subprocess is not updated. I'm pretty new to Python, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was approaching this the wrong way.

If you can either help explain what I'm doing wrong or a better solution to this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Are you wanting to update the command line or pass a message that the running program knows how to read? The former cannot be done AFAIK.

Comment: I'm guessing I **do** want to update the current command's parameters. I've been able to achieve what I want via `os.popen`, but I rather use the preferred (subprocess)

Comment: You cannot update its command line, as noted. The called program would have to written to receive and act on updates, say over stdin which seems to be what your code expects. Either share your `os.Popen` version and say how the results differ, or explain how the called program expects to receive updates.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been able to achieve what I want via os.popen, but I rather use the preferred (subprocess)

Each `os.popen()` starts a new shell process. `self.pipe.communicate()` doesn't start a new process: it writes *all* input, reads *all* output, and waits for the process to finish.

To start a command with a new set of parameters:

```
def update(self, bar, lyn):
    cmd = ['/bin/foo', '--bar', bar, '--lyn', lyn]
    self.processes.append(subprocess.Popen(cmd))
```